# Why light travels through shortest path during refraction?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, everyday-life, refraction

I know in order to compensate with change in speed but how does Light actually know which path is less dense or more dense?

Comment: I suggest you read 'QED' by Richard Feynman.

Answer (score 1):

Light doesn't actually 'know' which path is the shortest. In the quantum mechanical description, light actually takes all paths between point A and point B. It turns out that the phase of different paths adds up in such a way that the classical path corresponds to the one in which time taken is the least. For a more detailed explanation read QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter by Richard Feynman or section 26-6 of  http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_26.html

Comment: In addition to the previous answer, also in the classical theory light can be seen as a sum over plane waves. For a point B at  sufficient distance from a light source A only the plane wave with k-vector in the direction from A to B survives, the others cancel by interference.